# Using local images in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have 100's of points that have a photo for each of the points that are stored on my local drive. Each point has extended data, which includes the root of the picture name (bee-tree)

I have my  set up to reference using this line: img src="/files/$[geotourism_points/PIC_NAME].png", which works when I save it as a kml. However, when I save it as a .kmz it ignores the $[geotourism_points/ and only returns img src="files/PIC_NAME].png"

I have tried using relative path names using  ../files/image.png, /files/image.png, files/image.png (which one do you use?!!)

I still can't get it to work. Can I insert images into my balloon this way (local files), or will I have to load these to a server and reference them using the URL?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the whole code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>KmlFile</name>
    <Schema name="geotourism_points" id="geotourism_points_schema">
        <SimpleField type="string" name="MO_REGIO_1"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;MO_REGIO_1&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="TYPE"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;TYPE&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="NOTES_1"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;NOTES_1&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="WEBSITE"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;WEBSITE&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="SITE_NAME"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;SITE_NAME&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="LINK_2"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;LINK_2&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="ADDRESS"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;ADDRESS&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="PHONE"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;PHONE&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="PIC_NAME"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;PIC_NAME&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="string" name="SOURCE_1"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;SOURCE_1&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="int" name="NATUR"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;NATUR&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="int" name="CULTU"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;CULTU&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="int" name="REC"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;REC&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="int" name="ARCHEO"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;ARCHEO&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="int" name="HIST"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;HIST&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
        <SimpleField type="double" name="OBJECTID"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;OBJECTID&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
    </Schema>
    <StyleMap id="pointStyleMap">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#normPointStyle</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#normPointStyle0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="normPointStyle0">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table width="350"  cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top">
      <table  border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="files/lecl_logo.png" alt="logo"/>
          </td>
          <td width="70%"" align="left" valign="bottom">
            <font color="#2f4f4f" size="+2"><strong>$[geotourism_points/SITE_NAME]</strong></font>
            <br>
            <font color="#999999"><em>$[geotourism_points/TYPE] </em></font>
            <hr/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%" align="left" valign="top">
      <p>
        <br>
        <font color="#666666"><strong>Visitor's Information:</strong></font>
        <br><br>
        <font color="#999999">$[geotourism_points/ADDRESS]<br>$[geotourism_points/PHONE]</font>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="$[geotourism_points/WEBSITE]" target="_blank"><strong><em><font color="#2f4f4f">More Information...</font></strong></em></a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><img src="files/$[geotourism_points/PIC_NAME].png" alt="picture" width="100%" align="left" valign="middle"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="right"><font color="#999999" size="-1">$[geotourism_points/SOURCE_1]</font></td>
        </tr>
     </td>
</table>]]></text>
        </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="normPointStyle">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table width="350"  cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top">
      <table  border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="files/lecl_logo.png" alt="logo"/>
          </td>
          <td width="70%"" align="left" valign="bottom">
            <font color="#2f4f4f" size="+2"><strong>$[geotourism_points/SITE_NAME]</strong></font>
            <br>
            <font color="#999999"><em>$[geotourism_points/TYPE] </em></font>
            <hr/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%" align="left" valign="top">
      <p>
        <br>
        <font color="#666666"><strong>Visitor's Information:</strong></font>
        <br><br>
        <font color="#999999">$[geotourism_points/ADDRESS]<br>$[geotourism_points/PHONE]</font>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="$[geotourism_points/WEBSITE]" target="_blank"><strong><em><font color="#2f4f4f">More Information...</font></strong></em></a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><img src="files/$[geotourism_points/PIC_NAME].png" alt="picture" width="100%" align="left" valign="middle"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" align="right"><font color="#999999" size="-1">$[geotourism_points/SOURCE_1]</font></td>
        </tr>
     </td>
</table>]]></text>
        </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder id="layer 0">
        <name>geotourism_points</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Bee Tree County Park</name>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#geotourism_points_schema">
                    <SimpleData name="MO_REGIO_1">Confluence Region</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="TYPE">City/County Park</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="NOTES_1">riverfront</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="WEBSITE">stlouisco.com/ParksandRecreation/ParkPages/BeeTree</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="SITE_NAME">Bee Tree County Park</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="LINK_2"></SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="ADDRESS">2701 Finestown Road Saint Louis, MO 63129</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="PHONE"></SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="PIC_NAME">bee-tree</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="SOURCE_1">stlouisco.com</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="NATUR">1</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="CULTU">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="REC">1</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="ARCHEO">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="HIST">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">234</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-90.32844745921075,38.40766261103909,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Old St. Ferdinand Shrine</name>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#geotourism_points_schema">
                    <SimpleData name="MO_REGIO_1">Confluence Region</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="TYPE">Historic Site</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="NOTES_1"></SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="WEBSITE">http://www.oldstferdinandshrine.com/</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="SITE_NAME">Old St. Ferdinand Shrine</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="LINK_2"></SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="ADDRESS">#1 rue St. Francois, Florissant MO 63031</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="PHONE">Phone: (314) 837-2110</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="PIC_NAME">old-st-ferdinand-shrine</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="SOURCE_1">viewfrombackpew.blogspot.com</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="NATUR">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="CULTU">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="REC">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="ARCHEO">0</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="HIST">1</SimpleData>
                    <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">269</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-90.33389390094645,38.79675526749391,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your target audience. Do want to share KMZ on Internet or on an internal web site with photos on a shared network drive, etc?

If the KMZ file is local and relative to the KMZ file is the folder "files" with all your photos then it will display correctly in Google Earth as-is.

If you're serving the KMZ file from a website and the files are local then it won't work. The images must be co-resident with the KML file if using relative links.

```
<img src="files/$[geotourism_points/PIC_NAME].png" alt="picture" .../>
```

If you use absolute URLs in KML to the photo location then the KMZ will work where ever you host it.

```
<img src="http://server/files/$[geotourism_points/PIC_NAME].png" alt="picture" .../>
```

Alternative is embed the "files" folder and photos within the KMZ so the KML and photos are self-contained. Then you can use relative links in the KML.

Comment: I will be sharing the KMZ from a website. I thought I was embedding the "files" folder within the KMZ by saving the kml as a kmz. But it breaks the entity replacement /files/$[geotourism_points/PIC_NAME].png" and changes it to "files/PIC_NAME].png" so it can't find the relative path. It seems like it would be easiest to create a URL. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Why does it break the path name? I cannot find a workaround. I tried using filezilla to serve up the images, but that just brings up a whole bunch of other questions.

Comment: Try using src="./files/... Also, rename your .kmz to .zip then add the "files" folder to it as a zip file then rename it back to .kmz. Now does it work?

Comment: Neither of those work. Although, I'm not sure if I'm asking the question right. If it was just a strait path with an image name, and not an extended data element with the $[], then I know it would work. I just created a google site and loaded my images there. Thanks for your help. @JasonM1